# Sagemaker Kernel Error- Failed to Launch App: Error Retrieving Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to start my Sagemaker studio instance but it consistently gives this error:

> Failed to start kernel
> Failed to launch app [None]. Error when retrieving credentials from container-role: Error retrieving metadata: Received non 200 response (400) from ECS metadata: ResourceNotFoundException

I have tried re-installing jupyter .. restarted the kernel and the whole app but the issue was not resolved. I am using the base Data Science image and python3 kernel.
It was working normally till a day ago and I did no changes to the setup. There are also other studio instances running successfully with the same setup, so what could go wrong to suddenly cause this issue?

Comment: I've also started getting this error in my prod account which was running successfully

Answer (score 0):

AWS has released a new UI for Sagemaker Studio which appears to break existing Jupiter Instances.

The Instance type selector has been removed from the startup form, into its own menu item and form.

To fix, you need to delete any existing Apps in the affected user environment. Then recreate a new JupiterServer instance.

To update the JupyterServer app from the SageMaker console
Navigate to https://console.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/.

**Choose Domains.**

Select the Domain that includes the Studio application that you want to update.

Under User profiles, select your user name.

Under Apps, in the row displaying JupyterServer, choose Action, then choose Delete.

Choose Yes, delete app.

Type delete in the confirmation box.

Choose Delete.

After the app has been deleted, launch a new Studio app to get the latest version.

To update the JupyterServer app from inside Studio
Launch Studio.

On the top menu, choose File then Shut Down.

Choose one of the following options:

Shutdown Server – Shuts down the JupyterServer app. Terminal sessions, kernel sessions, SageMaker images, and instances aren't shut down. These resources continue to accrue charges.

Shutdown All – Shuts down all apps, terminal sessions, kernel sessions, SageMaker images, and instances. These resources no longer accrue charges.

Close the window.

After the app has been ***deleted***, launch a new Studio app to use the latest version.